# how to limit the results from datastore of google app engine.?

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, gql

Hello sir I am trying to get data from datastore of google app engine. I am executing following query to get data in descending order using app engine endpoint method.

```
Query highScorer = mgr.createQuery("select from CheckIn as CheckIn ORDER BY CheckIn.score DESC LIMIT 1");
```

Actually above query should give only one result but I am getting all entity in descending order. How to query for only one result.? Is there any thing wrong I am doing in Query? Thanks

Please let me know if i have to provide more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution. The above query should be written like below to get only one result.

```
Query highScorer = mgr.createQuery("select from CheckIn as CheckIn ORDER BY CheckIn.score DESC").setMaxResults(1);
```

Hope this will help someone. Thanks